# PHP + MSSQL data not inserting into table using sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with my **sqlsrv_query**. I have made a simple insert and update thru my application..my system popup insert successful..but when I use mssql studio management (MSSQL 2008 R2) also used EMS SQL, there is no data in my table..i try to used back my query form my application and paste at my query editor at mssql studio management, it’s works, **1 row(s) affected**. I don’t now what is actually happening. I am using **PHP 5.3.22**, driver **php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll**. I have no problem with my db connection..please help me.

```
$serverName = "servername"; $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"databasename", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password"); $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);



 function msexecDB($query, $conn){

     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or trigger_error("A SQL error has occurred.Your Query:---------" . $query . "---------"); return $result;

    }

    $insert_program = "INSERT INTO TB_PROGRAM (kod_program) VALUES ('$kod_program')";
    $row_program = msexecDB($insert_program, $conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of $kod_program.  It's possible you're inserting a blank string, which could have the appearance of having no record at all, yet would successfully run the query.